# ODBC Issues with Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to set up my Snowflake ODBC driver to work in EXCEL. I have managed to set up the driver and successfully connected it both SQL server and Tableau but for some reaon, whenever I try to connect to it through excel I get an error about the host not being resolved. Any help?

Comment: Have you configured the DSN for Snowflake in ODBC? If yes, are you trying to connect with Excel from **Data > Get External Data > New Database Query > From Database**?

Comment: Indeed I have. However, I have sussed it!! The ODBC driver had installed in c:\\programfiles. I moved this over to the system folder and boom, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Answering for completeness (curating tags):

As self-answered in the comments, this issue was resolved by moving the driver into the system folder.